# Calculate the average bits of byte in C

Tags: c

I try to writ a function that calculate the average bits of byte.

```
float AvgOnesOnBinaryString (int x)
```

for example:

-252 is 11111111 11111111 11111111 00000100

so the function return 6.25
because  ( 8+8+8+1) / 4 = 6.25

I have to use the function that count bits in char:

```
int countOnesOnBinaryString (char x){
    int bitCount = 0;
    while(x > 0)
    {
        if ( x & 1 == 1 )
            bitCount++;
        x = x>>1;
    }
    return bitCount;
}
```

I tried:

```
float AvgOnesOnBinaryString (int x){
    float total = 0;
    total += countOnesOnBinaryString((x >> 24));
    total += countOnesOnBinaryString((x >> 16));
    total += countOnesOnBinaryString((x >> 8));
    total += countOnesOnBinaryString(x);
    return total/4;
}
```

but I get the answae 0.25 and not 6.25
what could be the problem?

**UPDATE**

I can't change the AvgOnesOnBinaryString function signature.

Comment: You might be interested in `__builtin_popcount`. Anyway, `countOnesOnBinaryString` should take `unsigned` char.

Comment: You may have to convert `x` to `unsigned` because `x = x>>1;` may left-shift a `1` in if `x` is negative, resulting in a infinite loop.

Comment: Please learn how to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement, while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Indeed, if `char` is signed and `x` has the high bit set, then it is negative and `countOnesOnBinaryString(x)` will always return 0.

Comment: And regarding the comment by @FiddlingBits (apt name here ;) ) one should as a general rule never perform bitwise operations on signed integers (and `char` may be signed).

Comment: I can't change the AvgOnesOnBinaryString function signature.  It is part of the task.

Comment: @galleshem Then the task is ill-defined. Sure you can cast the input, but it does not make sense to have it signed in the first place. Or you could limit it to work with positive range only.

Comment: I guess you can check the size of `int` on your system and then calculate, but I think that Eugene is right and that just returning the average bits for 32 bit is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

The C language allows compilers to define `char` as either a signed or unsigned type.  I suspect it is signed on your platform, meaning that a byte like `0xff` is likely interpreted as `-1`.  This means that the `x > 0` test in `countOnesOnBinaryString` yields false, so `countOnesOnBinaryString(0xff)` would return 0 instead of the correct value 8.

You should change `countOnesOnBinaryString` to take an argument of type `unsigned char` instead of `char`.

For somewhat related reasons, it would also be a good idea to change the argument of `AvgOnesOnBinaryString` to be `unsigned int`.  Or even better, `uint32_t` from `<stdint.h>`, since your code assumes the input value is 32 bits, and (unsigned) int is allowed to be of some other size.

Comment: @Nate Eldredgo, Thanks! but I can't change the AvgOnesOnBinaryString function signature.

Comment: @galleshem: So then `unsigned char ux = (unsigned char)x;` as the first line of the function, and change all remaining occurrences of `x` to `ux`.

Answer (score 1):

There is one algorithm that gives you the count of the number of `1` bits in an `unsigned` variable far more quickly.  Only 5 iterations are needed in a 32 bit integer.  I'll show it to you in C for a full length 64 bit `unsigned` number, so probably you can guess the pattern and why it works (it is explained below):

```
uint64_t 
no_of_1_bits(uint64_t the_value)
{
    the_value = ((the_value & 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa) >>  1) + (the_value & 0x5555555555555555);
    the_value = ((the_value & 0xcccccccccccccccc) >>  2) + (the_value & 0x3333333333333333);
    the_value = ((the_value & 0xf0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0) >>  4) + (the_value & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f);
    the_value = ((the_value & 0xff00ff00ff00ff00) >>  8) + (the_value & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ff);
    the_value = ((the_value & 0xffff0000ffff0000) >> 16) + (the_value & 0x0000ffff0000ffff);
    the_value = ((the_value & 0xffffffff00000000) >> 32) + (the_value & 0x00000000ffffffff);

    return the_value;
}
```

The number of `1` bits will be in the 64bit value of `the_value`.  If you divide the result by eight, you'll have the average of 1 bits per byte for an `unsigned long`  (beware of making the shifts with `signed chars` as the sign bit is replicated, so your algorithm will never stop for a negative number)

For 8 bit bytes, the algorithm reduces to:

```
uint8_t 
no_of_1_bits(uint8_t the_value)
{
    the_value = ((the_value & 0xaa) >> 1) + (the_value & 0x55);
    the_value = ((the_value & 0xcc) >> 2) + (the_value & 0x33);
    the_value = ((the_value & 0xf0) >> 4) + (the_value & 0x0f);

    return the_value;
}
```

and again, the number of 1 bits is in the variable `the_value`.

The idea of this algorithm is to produce in the first step the sum of each pair of bits in a two bit accumulator (we shift the left bit of a pair to the right to align it with the right one, then we add them together, and in parallel for each pair of bits).  As the accumulators are two bits, it is impossible to overflow (so there's never a carry from a pair of bits to the next, and we use the full integer as a series of two bit registers to add the sum)

Then we sum each pair of bits in an accumulator of four bits and again, that never overflows... let's do the same thing with the nibbles we got, and sum them into registers of 8 bits.... If it was impossible to overflow a 4 bit accumulator with two bits, it is more impossible to overflow an 8 bit accumulator with four bit addings.... and continue until you add the left half of the word with the right half.  You finally end with the sum of all bits in one full length register of the word length.

Easy, isn't it? :)